# How and when does `exec` change the effective user ID, when the set-user-ID is set for the executable file

Tags: linux, unix, system-calls

My question comes from reading APUE.

In Unix or Linux, when a process executes an executable file by calling the `exec` function, if the set-user-ID bit is set for the executable file, `exec` changes the effective user ID to the owner of the file.

1. How does `exec` change the effective user ID?

   Does `exec` make the change by calling `setuid`, or by some other function?
2. When does `exec` change the effective user ID?

   Does `exec` change the effective
   user ID of the process **before** or **after** the kernel performs
   the permission test on whether the process is allowed to executes
   the file?

   Equivalently to the above question, right before  the kernel performs the permission test on whether the
   process is allowed to executes the file, is the effective ID of the
   process the one **before** or **after** `exec` changes the effective
   user ID to the owner of the file?

Thanks.

Comment: I think you confused `execve(2)` (system call) with `exec(3)` (library function). `exec` would call `execve` which is a system call and would be executed by the kernel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll cover [UNIX V7](http://www.tuhs.org/cgi-bin/utree.pl?file=V7/usr/sys/sys/sys1.c) here. There are dozens of versions of UNIX, but their implementations of exec are pretty similar.

The effective uid is a field in the [per-process user structure](http://www.tuhs.org/cgi-bin/utree.pl?file=V7/usr/sys/h/user.h), and is kept in sync with a similar field in the [process structure](http://www.tuhs.org/cgi-bin/utree.pl?file=V7/usr/sys/h/proc.h). In V7, changing the effective uid is done with two simple assignment statements:

```
/*
 * set SUID/SGID protections, if no tracing
 */
if ((u.u_procp->p_flag&STRC)==0) {
    if(ip->i_mode&ISUID)
        if(u.u_uid != 0) {
            u.u_uid = ip->i_uid;
            u.u_procp->p_uid = ip->i_uid;
        }
    if(ip->i_mode&ISGID)
        u.u_gid = ip->i_gid;
}
```

[Exercise: what does the check for `(u.u_uid != 0)` wind up doing, and why was it dropped from the exec code in subsequent versions of UNIX?]

The first thing `exec` does is check permissions, by calling `access`, which uses the process's effective uid and gid. It does this long before the setuid bit of the file is even looked at.

```
if ((ip = namei(uchar, 0)) == NULL)
    return;
if(access(ip, IEXEC))
    goto bad;
```

The uid change is done after all permission and magic number checking and memory allocation has been done. As the code says shortly before the allocation and uid setting:

```
/*
 * allocate and clear core
 * at this point, committed
 * to the new image
 */
```

Answer (score 2):

According to wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid:

1. I think (not sure) that no other syscalls are explicitly involved; but exec() will probably do an internal call to setuid code.
2. exec() changes the effective user ID **after** having decided that the file can be executed. Otherwise, it would be a non-sense.